# Lie derivative of an action of a compact Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-actions

> Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $M$ Be a smooth manifold on which $G$ acts .  Let $p \in M$ and  $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ such that the vector field $X_M$ defined by $$X_M(m) = \frac{d}{dt}{\vert_{t=0}} e^{tX}.m , \quad m \in M, $$
> vanishes at $p$, which implies that $e^{tX}.p=p.$

In page 213 of the book Heat kernels and Dirac operators, the authors say that the Lie action $\mathcal{L}(X)\xi= [X_M, \xi]$ on $\Gamma (M, TM)$ gives rise to an invertible transformation $L_p$ of $T_pM$ (which is defined by $L_p : T_pM \rightarrow T_pM, Y \longmapsto L_p(Y) = [X_M, \tilde{Y}](p)$, where $\tilde{Y}$ is a vector field which at the point $p$ is equal to $Y$ .)

Next, the authors claim that the map $L_p$ has only imaginary eigenvalues since it is the Lie derivative of an action of a compact Lie group.

Why is $L_p$  the Lie derivative of an action of $G$ ?

I think what the authors mean is that if  $a(t) : M \rightarrow M, m \longmapsto e^{tX}.m,$ then

$$L_p (Y)f = (da(t)(Y))f, \quad \forall Y \in T_pM , \forall f \in C^\infty(M),$$

but $L_p (Y)f = \frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=0} Y_{a(t)(p)}(f \circ a(t))$ and $(da(t)(Y))f = Y(f \circ a(t)),$

however, I don't see why they are equal ?

Comment: It's not even clear how $L_p$ is invertible. What if the action is trivial?

Comment: @Arctic Char, I found an answer to this question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752137/the-lie-derivative-by-an-infinitesimal-action-is-invertible-at-an-isolated-zero.

Comment: They assume that $p$ is an isolated fixed point though.

Comment: Ooops, yes I forgot to mention it, but I don't think it is needed in my question, is it ?